# probabilistic termination of transparent bounces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

From Cycles [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html) about Light Paths:

> The maximum number of transparent bounces is controlled separately
> from other bounces. It is also possible to use probabilistic
> termination of transparent bounces, which might help rendering many
> layers of transparency.

What should I do to start using this probabilistic termination?

Comment: Thank you! I've already started to forget 2.79 )) There's still Min Transparent Bounces chekbox in 2.9, it is in the Render Settings > Sampling > Advanced but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Blender Manual > Light Paths > Bounce Control](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html#bounce-control)

> Light paths are **terminated probabilistically** when specifying a minimum
> number of light bounces lower than the maximum. In that case, paths
> longer than minimum will be randomly stopped when they are expected to
> contribute less light to the image. This will still converge to the same image, but renders faster while possibly being noisier.

[image]

<sup>[Related thread on BlenderArtists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/the-new-transparency-bounces-in-blender-2-8/)</sup>